# Router navigation in VIPER + Swinject

Tags: swift, viper-architecture, swinject

I have `mainAssembly`:

```
final class ApplicationAssembly {
    var assembler: Assembler
    
    init(with assemblies: [Assembly]) {
        self.assembler = Assembler(assemblies)
    }
}
```

With two module for example:

```
var applicationAssembly = ApplicationAssembly(with: [ProfileAssembly(), StoriesAssembly()])
window?.rootViewController = applicationAssembly.assembler.resolver.resolve(ProfileViewController.self)
```

Here is `ProfileAssembly`:

```
import Swinject

class ProfileAssembly: Assembly {
    
    func assemble(container: Container) {
        container.register(ProfileInteractorInput.self) { (r, presenter: ProfilePresenter) in
            let interactor = ProfileInteractor()
            interactor.output = presenter
            return interactor
        }
        container.register(ProfilePresenterInput.self){ (r, viewController: ProfileViewController) in
            let presenter = ProfilePresenter()
            presenter.output = viewController
            presenter.interactor = r.resolve(ProfileInteractorInput.self, argument: presenter)
            presenter.router = r.resolve(ProfileRouterInput.self, argument: viewController)
            return presenter
        }
        container.register(ProfileRouterInput.self) { (r, viewController: ProfileViewController) in
            let router = ProfileRouter()
            router.viewController = viewController
            return router
        }
        container.register(ProfileViewController.self) { r in
            let viewController = ProfileViewController()
            viewController.presenter = r.resolve(ProfilePresenterInput.self, argument: viewController)
            return viewController
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, however i don't know how to configure my router to navigate to another module:

```
protocol ProfileRouterInput: class {
    func openStories()
}

class ProfileRouter: ProfileRouterInput {
    
    weak var viewController: UIViewController?
    
    func openStories() {
        
    }
}
```

Before Swinject I've used wireframes where I had something like `build()` function to return specific VC. But since my assemblies are in the main Assembler container, should I have a direct access from any routers in my app to the main assembler?

Comment: Swinject is irrelevant. It does dependency injection. It has nothing to do with routing. How would you do this _without_ Swinject? Well, do it that same way.

Comment: @matt yeah, i know, i just wanna know what is the most common/best practice to use swinject in the viper architecture. I guess this is not an elegant solution, if i just add a func in one module's assembly which return current vc and use this func in another module's router